# Запись видео

Tags: html5, видео

Доброго времени суток! html5 позволяет захватывать видео с web камеры - есть ли возможность сохранять это видео?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вам подойдет совершенно бесплатный **[Red5](http://www.red5.org/)**
Вот **[Demo](http://www.red5-recorder.com/demo.php)**
Цитата с **wikipedia**

```
Red5 это RTMP медиасервер с открытым исходным кодом, написанный на Java. Red5 поддерживает:

 - Потоковое Аудио/Видео (FLV и MP3)
 - Запись пользовательских потоков данных (Recording Client Streams) (только для FLV)
 - Shared Objects
 - Live Stream Publishing
 - Remoting
```

**[Руководство по установке и настройке](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143554/)**